# SQL Server table design advice

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be a stupid question.

Some efficiency advice for SQL Server 2008 R2 although these servers will be upgraded to 2014 over the next few months. I am creating 3 tables.

- `t1` has many columns of varying types and an identity numeric ID which is the primary key. I anticipate this table to get into the low 1000s of rows.
- `t2` has a one-many relationship with t1. It's primary key will be a composite of a t2 ID and t1 ID. The t2 numeric ID will be sent by the frontend application and will be unique per t1 ID.  I anticipate this table to get to 50000+ rows. Other than these 2 IDs it will contain a handful of varchar columns of varying lengths.
- `t3` has a one-many relationship with t2. It's primary key could be a composite of a t3 ID, the t1 ID, and the t2 ID.  Again the t3 numeric ID will be sent by the frontend application and will be unique per t2 ID. I anticipate this table to get to several million rows.  Other than these 3 IDs it will contain a small number of date or numeric columns.

My question is within t2 should I set up an identity column which t3 will refer to essentially meaning that the primary key of t3 will be 2 columns instead of 3, i.e. a t3 ID and the identity column from t2. Would this be more efficient? Should this identity column within t2 be indexed? to help with joins?

Should I be doing anything else?

Comment: What sort of searches will you be performing most frequently? will you be searching `t3` using either `t1` or `t2` keys or would data from the other fields be used? Your answer may make surrogate or natural keys a better choice.

Comment: Within both **t2** and **t3** it is unlikely any searches will be executed independently although this may come up in the future although I doubt it. Queries against these tables will be driven by joins to **t1**.  The vast majority of day-day searches will be for 1 t1 record and whatever is in t2 for that t1 ID and whatever is in t3 for those t1|t2 IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought concerns the statement

> ... the [t2|t3] numeric ID will be sent by the frontend application
>   ...

If you are generating unique identifiers for use in a database I would suggest you let the database generate the numbers. Unless you can be *absolutely sure* the application will not generate duplicate IDs.

In response to your comment, here's the difference when using surrogate keys (if I have understood your table structure correctly)

```
     +----+   +----+   +----+
     |    |   |    |   |    |
     | t1 +---+ t2 +---+ t3 |
     |    |   |    |   |    |
     +----+   +----+   +----+

keys: t1.id    t1.id    t1.id
               t2.id    t2.id
                        t3.id
```

A change to surrogate keys it would not change `t1` (no need); `t2` would also remain the same, but you would need to change the `t2.id` from being a line number to a unique number primary key [pk]. Trouble is you will have to store the 'line number' as another field in the table.

The main difference would be `t3` only needing the `t2.pk` and its own row identifier, rather than all three table identifiers.

```
      +----+   +----+   +----+
      |    |   |    |   |    |
      | t1 +---+ t2 +---+ t3 |
      |    |   |    |   |    |
      +----+   +----+   +----+

keys: t1.id     t2.pk    t2.pk
                t1.id    t3.pk
```

Would this be better? I'm not sure. It would also depend in the type, and frequency, of the queries you are running against the tables (see my comment on your question).

If you mainly query by `id` then the first layout will be the best - lookup rows in `t3` without having to join to `t2` or `t1`. But if you need information from those other tables to do your searches, a surrogate key structure may make your joins less verbose.

Ultimately, this is all premature optimisation (in terms of query performance) because you won't know what performs best until you implement it.

Comment: They should always be unique.  In the frontend the t2 ID is essentially a line number on the screen within each t1 record.  When data is changed within the frontend the app should check if the record exists to see if a dynamic update or insert SQL statement needs to be generated.  What structure would you suggest?  If I use singe column identities as primary keys I will still need to store combinations of [t1|t2] or [t1|t2|t3] depending on the table.  What is best within the database to ensure these are not duplicated?

Comment: @Darybrain - I've updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I typically create identity int primary keys for this and have this be the clustered index.

I would not have t2 or t3 have an id that is composite, rather a separate field and set up a foreign key constraint.

The clustered index and foreign key will be all the indexing you need (for the joins).  You may need additional indexes based on your queries.

I have set this up on tables with hundred of millions of rows and get query results in under 1 second.

Comment: Taking t2 as an example, if I create an identity column as the clustered primary I still need to have the t1 ID and the t2 ID (basically a line number for each t1 record) I get from the frontend application in the table.  How is best to ensure that the combination of the two do not get duplicated?  Will these 2 fields be in the constraint you mentioned?

Comment: @Darybrain - You can use a `UNIQUE` index on the key fields to prevent duplicates while having a single numeric key field.

Comment: Why is the front end generating keys?  Unless the application is controlling multiple data stores I do not understand the need.  @Darybrain is correct as well, you can add a unique constraint to prevent duplication but that will cause errors you will have to trap and handle.  The key question is why the front end has any control on the RDBMS.